# How can I get Mac RDC client to connect to W2K3 after enabling FIPS support?

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac-osx, remote-desktop, fips-140-2

Recently we enabled FIPS 140-2 Encryption Algorithms on our W2K3 server per http://chadamberg.com/drupal/IISCryptography and now my Mac RDP 2.1.1 client won't connect. I get:

"Remote Desktop Connection cannot verify the identity of the computer to which you want to connect...."

My client is set to "Always connect, even if authentication fails" but that doesn't seem to help. I'm guessing there's some incompatibility between FIPS support and Mac RDP. I can still get in via my Win7 RDP client. I tried CoRD as well, but it failed to connect.

Any ideas on how to reinstate Mac RDC to this server, or am I at the mercy of MS updating their Mac client?

Comment: Good question... racking my brains for ideas... TS web app won't work due to Active-X requirements... mac client does not support TS gateway redirection... maybe citrix? Personally I'd use vmware view to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to reinstate Mac RDC to this server, or am I at the mercy of MS updating their Mac client?

The Mac RDP client is likely not presenting a 'valid' MS client certificate to the other server, so it's refused.  Unless the new security features are enabled on Mac RDP it won't work and you'll need to use Windows or something out-of-band.